# Dissecting the [sector] tag

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

While asking [an other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35664088/installing-grub-grub2-programmatically), I noticed that the tag [sector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sector) currently mainly represents two things. If you look at the questions that use this tag, 'sector' can mean:

- Disk Sector
- Geometrical sector (e.g. Circle sector)

I think it should be "divided" into two tags, for example [disk-sector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/disk-sector) and [geometry-sector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/geometry-sector).

Stats: On the 77 questions with the tag [sector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sector), 15 talks about [geometry-sector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/geometry-sector) and the rest should go in [disk-sector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/disk-sector).

Comment: Do you have any idea of how many are disk, vs geometry?

Comment: This question needs more statistics, good on you for not jumping to ask for a burnination though.

Comment: Not necessarily "the rest." [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34210785/what-does-cpu-performs-an-endless-jump-mean) has a sector tag, but I have no idea why. A number of the disk-sector questions look off-topic to me. That may also be true about geometry-sector.

Comment: Maybe we need to close some of these questions first as clean up and see what's left.

Comment: The title should be, "Dissecting [sector]"